# set referrerPolicy on an Angular HttpClient request

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Is there any way to set referrerPolicy on an Angular HttpClient request? I just tried:

```
   let headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers = headers.set('referrerPolicy', 'no-referrer-when-downgrade');
```

but It doesnt work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should be ‘ Referrer-Policy’..

Comment: @MikeOne It doesnt seems to work